# Error while trying to slice list

Tags: python-3.x, slice

I am a new programmer! And I have just started using Python and I really like it ! But now I have stumbled on a particular error I cant seem to understand.

Now I am not going to post my exact code here but this is what the basic idea is:

here is the edited code:

```
def function(parameter1, parameter2):
return parameter1[parameter2 + 1:]
```

When I use numbers for parameter1 it runs fine, for example:

```
function([5,6,7,8,9], 3)
```

but when I use letters and numbers such as:

```
function("ABC34",3)
```

it gives error:

```
builtins.TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

EDIT:

okay so I am basically looking for an output like this:

```
 function([0,11,42,53,74,59,62,70,81,98], 3)
```

output should be:

```
[74, 59, 62, 70, 81, 98, 53, 0, 11, 42]
```

now by reading the comments below I am sort of thinking that maybe slicing wont be able to produce what I am looking for??

Comment: how are you using the return value of `function`? Where are you getting that error?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem; please post your *exact* code. Your function definition as-is is invalid.

Comment: indentation is broken in code

Comment: okay give me a second to update my post

Comment: @user2891763 given..:)

Answer (score 2):

Strings are iterable just like lists.  So break it down into what each piece of your function is doing to a string:

Left:

```
#parameter1[parameter2 + 1:]

'abc34'[3+1:]
Out[13]: '4'
```

Middle:

```
#[parameter2]

[3]
Out[14]: [3]
```

Right:

```
#parameter1[:parameter2]

'abc34'[:3]
Out[15]: 'abc'
```

And then you can see that python doesn't know how to do `'4' + [3]`.

Answer (score 0):

(n python 2.7.3 I get a slightly more helpful error:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

The issue is that you can't concatenate `[parameter2]` (an integer list) to `parameter1[parameter2 + 1:]` (which is a string when `parameter1` is a string).

Strings can be sliced but they're not completely interchangeable with character arrays.